# Erlang - Creating list with predefined data

Tags: erlang

I just started playing with Erlang and found something that bother me a lot. I think it just because Erlang is my first "function-like" language.

So, I want to create a list filled with some predefined data, like [1,1,1,1,1] or [a,a,a] and I can't find any Erlang function for this? Is there any? Or the only way is to create such function by hand, like here:

```
-module(listhelp).

-export([create/2]).

create(NumberOfElements, Element) ->
    create(NumberOfElements, Element, []).

create(0, Element, List) ->
    List;

create(NumberOfElements, Element, List) ->
    create(NumberOfElements-1, Element, [Element|List]).
```

Thanks in advance fo answers!

Comment: Your implementation is almost identical to [the implementation of lists:duplicate](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/01a13c00f67112e7996e45439d4eec9e6aa414ce/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L279-L291), only the test for `N` being a non-negative integer is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is lists:duplicate/2 what you want?

```
1> lists:duplicate(5,1).
[1,1,1,1,1].
```